# SQLite.swift pod: Swift Compiler Error in Xcode 8.3 beta 2

Tags: xcode, sqlite.swift

Project builds fine in Xcode 8.2.1, but in 8.3b2 the pod SQLite.swift produces >18 issues like:

```
Swift Compiler Error 
  Build a shadowed submodule 'Darwin.POSIX.basic' 
  module.modulemap
```

Errors appear to relate to redefinition of basic types such as _int8_t

Is there a simple resolution/workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to see this resolved in subsequent betas, but happy to note that this is no longer an issue.

I'm not quite sure which of these items actually resolved it for me:

1. Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162) - release version
2. Using SQLite.swift (0.11.2) - I don't think this has changed
3. Clean Build Folder (Cmd-Opt-Shift-K)

[This issue](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/617) (suspiciously similar to this post) confirms that 0.11.3 of the pod tests against Xcode 8.3